# How Use Refresh indicator on pdf/file viewer in flutter

Tags: flutter, pull-to-refresh

using `stack` widget inside a child of `refresh indicator` gets the screen no scrollable.

Tried Stack widget but no refresh indicator found instead screen stucks

```
plugin -> pdf_render: ^1.0.12

Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: widget.darkMode ? DARK_BACKGROUND : Colors.white,
  appBar: AppBar()
  body: Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: PdfViewer.openFutureFile(
          () async {
            await DefaultCacheManager().emptyCache();
            var pdf = (await DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(pdfUrl)).path;
            return pdf;
          },
          viewerController: controller,
          onError: (err) => print(err),
          params: PdfViewerParams(
            padding: 10,
            minScale: 1.0,
          ),
        )
      ),
      Widget2(),
      Widget3(),
      ....
    ],
  ),
),
```

I want to have a refresh indiacator on pdf viewer.

I thing pdf is alredy a scrollable widget that's why it might conflicts refresh indicator.

Comment: `Stack` is not scrollable widget. `ResfresIndicator` required scrollable widget. like `ListView`, `SingleChildScrollView`, etc.

Comment: Kindly, provide code which you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your PdfViewer.openFutureFile widget in Listview and set List view physics NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() its Works

**physics:NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()**

```
  RefreshIndicator(
     onRefresh: () {},
      child:ListView(
      physics:NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
   childern : [
       PdfViewer.openFutureFile(
          () async {
        await DefaultCacheManager().emptyCache();
        var pdf = (await 
           DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(pdfUrl)).path;
        return pdf;
      },
      viewerController: controller,
      onError: (err) => print(err),
      params: PdfViewerParams(
        padding: 10,
        minScale: 1.0,
        ),
      )
    ),
  ],

   ),
  ),
 ),
```

Comment: Thank you for reaching out, but I am not using any listview or gridview, it is file viewer like pdf that conflicts scrollable nature of pdf document

Comment: Can you please share code ?

Comment: sure, code is now appended with abow qns.